# What is the meaning of "%-*.*s" in a printf format string?

Tags: c, printf

```
#define FMT "%-*.*s e = %6ld, chars = %7ld, stat = %3u: %c %c %c %c\n"
```

This macro is passed into the `printf` function. What does `%-*.*s` mean?

Comment: SO is not intended to serve as replacement for ordinary man pages. Format specifiers for `printf` are described on any man page for this function.

Comment: I learned something from this question so +1 from me.

Comment: I think the man page is sufficiently hard to understand to justify that question (and I learned something as well, probably because it wasn't part in the K&R printf).

Comment: As an aside, the format doesn't have to be a string literal; it can be a regular pointer (e.g. `char *fmt = "%d"; printf(fmt, 3);`). This implies that you can assemble it with sprintf programmatically as well. It is fairly uncommon but very flexible when needed.

Answer (score 67):

You can read the [manual page for printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html). But it's more like a law text than a tutorial, so it will be hard to understand.

I didn't know `*.*` and had to read the man page myself. It's interesting. Let's start with a simple `printf("%s", "abc")`. It will print the string `abc`.

`printf("%8s", "abc")` will print      `abc`, including 5 leading spaces: 8 is the "field width". Think of a table of data with column widths so that data in the same column is vertically aligned. The data is by default right-aligned, suitable for numbers.

`printf("%-8s", "abc")` will print `abc`     , including 5 trailing spaces: the minus indicates left alignment in the field.

It is important that this is a **minimum** field width: In spite of the field width being only 8, `printf("%-8s", "1234567890")` will print all 10 characters, without any spaces.

Now for the star:
`printf("%-*s", 8, "abc")` will print the same as the ordinary `printf("%-8s", "abc")`. The star indicates that the field width (here: 8) will be passed as a parameter to `printf`. That way it can be changed programmatically.<sup>1</sup>

Now for the "precision", that is:
`printf("%-*.10s", 8, "1234567890123")` will print only `1234567890`, omitting the last three characters: the "precision" is the **maximum** field width in case of strings. This is one of the rare cases (apart from rounding, which is also controlled by the precision value) where data is truncated by `printf`.

And finally
`printf("%-*.*s", 8, 10, "1234567890123")` will print the same as before, but the maximum field width is given as a parameter, too.

---

<sup>1</sup>It is also possible to pass a regular char pointer as a format string, instead of a string literal. That pointer can point to a buffer where a format string has been composed at runtime, for example with `ssprintf`, allowing for even more runtime flexibility. This is pretty rare, partly owing to the fact that the actual parameters to `printf` are fixed at compile time, which mostly determines the conversion specifiers at compile time as well. Most likely, it is just the field width that is undetermined at compile time.

Comment: I just wrote up my answer because I didn't know what the `*.*` did either.  Your answer is a better explanation.