# What does printf("%*.*s",int,int,char *) mean in c?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I got a code snippet in which there is a statement

```
printf("%*.*s");
```

what does the `%*.*s` mean?

The code is

```
char *c="**********";
int i,n=4;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
printf("%*.*s\n",i,i,c);
}
```

Output is:

```
*
**
***
****
```

Comment: It means some time in the [formatting chart for `printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) would be well spent. In this case, it also means a malformed `printf` invocation, since you're supplying none of the required arguments for that format specifier in your call.

Comment: flags, width, .precision and modifiers (in that order), are optional

In your case:
width: * = The width is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.  
.precision: .* = The precision is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.  
specifier: s = char*

reference:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776824/what-is-the-meaning-of-s-in-a-printf-format-string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read the spec of [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/):

> `%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier`
>
> `s`  String of characters
>
> `*`   The width is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.

For strings the width is Minimum number of characters to be printed (padding may be added).

> `.*`  The precision is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.

For strings the precission is the Maximum number of characters to be printed.

Your program is not passing the required optional arguments (witdh, precission, the string to be printed). Behavior will be undefined (likely a crash).

Answer (score 6):

*To start with, first let me clarify, the `*`s in the format string here are not for printing `*` charcater(s) itself. They do have a special meaning in this context.*

---

In your case,

```
 printf("%*.*s");
```

the first `*` is the *field width*, the second `*` one (to be precise, `.*`) denotes *precision.*

Both the `*`s need an `int` argument to supply the respective value.

To quote the standard,

> As noted above, a field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk. In this case, an `int` argument supplies the field width or precision. The arguments specifying field width, or precision, or both, shall appear (in that order) before the argument (if any) to be converted. A negative field width argument is taken as a - flag followed by a positive field width. A negative precision argument is taken as if the precision were omitted.

So, a generic form for a conversion specifier to appear is

```
 %[flags]<field width><precision><length modifier>[conversion specifier character]
```

Please note all the elements in `<>` are optional, only `[flags]` and `[conversion specifier character]` are mandatory. That said, the requirement says

> **Zero or more** flags

thus, *essentially* making `[flags]` also as optional.

Please refer to `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.1 for more info.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass 3 arguments for this statement as `printf("%*.*s",a,b,str);` where `a` and `b` are integers and `str` is string.

It prints out `a` number of characters with first `b` characters of `str` as last `b` characters of output. First `b-a` characters will be space(' ').

Answer (score 0):

.* The precision is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.

printf("%.*s\n", 20, "rabi");